# how to make it so that if a message is dm'ed a bot the message is shown in a channel in server discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I need help making a discord bot so that if a message is dm'ed a bot the message is shown in a channel in server discord.js

Comment: Can we see your attempt at this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic way to do this is to just see if the message channel type is a DM (`if (message.channel.type === 'dm')`), and if it is, we will send the message content to a certain channel (`client.channels.cache.get('channel_id').send(message.content)`).
Put together, it is like this:

```js
if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        client.channels.cache.get('channel_id').send(message.content)
}
```

That will only send the message content.
If you want to see who sent the message, you can do something like this:

```js
client.channels.cache.get('channel_id').send(`New message by ${message.author.tag}: ${message.content}`)
```

This well send you something like `New message by Username#0000: Hello world!`.
**(This is a good place to stop if you want a simple `if` statement that gets who sent it and the message content.)**
We can then go on to create this as an embed:

```js
var dmMessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed() // This creates an empty embed
.setTitle("New DM!") // This sets the title of the embed to 'New DM!'
.setDescription(`**New message from ${message.author.tag}**(${message.author.id})\n**Message content**: ${message.content}`) // This is the main text of the embed
.setColor("GREEN") // This sets the color of the embed. It can be RED, PURPLE, etc. or it can be a hex code
.setTimestamp() // This shows the time when the embed was sent. ( it would also be the time the message was sent )
.setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL()) // This sets the bots tag and profile picture to the footer
.setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})) // This sets the 'author' of the embed. It will show up at the top of the embed. The {dynamic: true} just makes it animate the profile photo if it is animated

if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
    client.channels.cache.get('channel_id').send(dmMessage) // Sends the embed to the specified channel ID
}
```

---

You can always create a variable like `var dmID = "your_channel_id"` and replace the `'channel_id'` in the `client.channels.cache.get` with `dmID` so you can change the variable and it will change everywhere.